# I want to print my name's letters one by one

Tags: java

I want to print my name's letters one by one like so:

Result:

```
A
Af
Afs
afsh
afsha
afshan
.....
```

I've tried this coding but its a simple loop and it showing my complete name.

```
char[]aar={'a','f','s','h','a','n'};

for(int b=0; b<1;b++){
    String str=new String(aar);
    System.out.println(""+str);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. You can use the `substring` method of String class.

```
    String name="yourname";
    for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(name.substring(0,i+1));
    }
```

Comment: I got my result.Thank you very much. Its simple and easy.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to print a *substring* of your name on each step. So start with the complete name:

```
String name = "Afshan";
```

and then loop for as many letters as there are (using `String.length()` to check) and then print the substring from the start to that iteration number - use `name.substring(0, i + 1)` to get the relevant substring where `i` is the variable in the loop. Read the [documentation for `substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) carefully to see what each of the parameters means (and why you want `i + 1` rather than `i`).

It's important to use `i` in the body of the loop, otherwise you *will* be printing the same thing on each iteration.

I won't provide the full code here, as you're trying to learn (yay) but as an aside, try to avoid using `"" + ...` - in your existing code, you don't need it anyway, as `str` is already a string, but if you *do* need to convert a different type into a string, use `String.valueOf(x)` instead. That says exactly what you want to do, whereas concatenation with an empty string doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using nested for-loops

```
    char[]aar={'a','f','s','h','a','n'};
    //count just from 1 to the length of array
    for(int a = 1; a<aar.length; a++)
    {
        //print elements from 0-1, 0-2 ,0-3, and so on.
        for(int b=0; b<a;b++)
        {
            System.out.print(aar[b]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another version.
Please use meaningful names and correct indentation.
Note that the outer for loop needs the equals. Otherwise it doesn't work.

```
char[] chars = {'a', 'f', 's', 'h', 'a', 'n'};


for (int length = 1; length <= chars.length; length++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.print(chars[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```